# Is $this->__invoke(); 100% safe and valid in PHP?

Tags: php, class, magic-methods

```
// in class
public function test () {
    $this->__invoke();
}

$inst->test();
```

This test runs without any error.

My question:  is there some reason why this should not be done? Are there any corner cases, hidden caveats, or does it behave like any regular function/method?

Comment: from what i understand it will cause an infinite loop, as is will continually call itself again and agin, however worth testing with some form of out put, maybe echo a count?

Comment: Test works fine, no infinite loops. Why do you think there'll be looping? It's exactly the same call as if calling normal method. I just want to be sure that there aren't some hidden/arcane pitfalls.

Comment: @andrewhutchings __invoke() is called when an instance is executed as a function. You probably were thinking about __call(), but it only works when calling inaccessible methods. Not the case. :)

Comment: The reason why you shouldn't use it, is that it will not work unless you implemented `__invoke()`. If you implement `__invoke()` it makes no sense to call `test()` anymore since you can call the object directly, that's the meaning of `__invoke()`.. Check the documentation

Comment: Come on people, not twilight zone again. I know what __invoke() does. It makes sense to create many wrapper functions around particular function if someone needs that. But that was not my question. My question was is it safe, is it like normal php f(), are there some less known issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should not work since there is no `__invoke()` method in your class:

```
class SomeClass {
    public function test()
    {
        $this->__invoke();
    }
}

$inst = new SomeClass();
$inst->test();
```

http://3v4l.org/JOBXn.

If you implement `__invoke()`, that should work:

```
class SomeClass {
    public function __invoke()
    {
        var_dump('Invoke!');
    }

}

$inst = new SomeClass();
$inst();
```

http://3v4l.org/mpG5d.

Magic methods can be called directly as you can see in the second test, but in my opinion it is not a good idea since they are some kind of hooks and their code could be executed unexpectedly.

Comment: Just a hint: `3v4l.org` is really nice, I'm using it too! But you should put the code examples into your answer and additionally add a link to `3v4l.org` if you like, but the essential part of the answer should be here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok, I will do that next time. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I did similar tests prior posting this question. I see it's working :) That was not my question. I want to know if it will work 100%, are there any hidden, auto mechanisms that I should be aware of etc.

Comment: There are also no `class` keyword, {,  $init = new CL() in my sample,... It's just a sample...

Comment: It will work like any other method. The difference between magic methods and regular methods is that magic methods are called internally in some circunstances: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: Are you sure that magic methods are like any other methods when called like `$this->__magic...();` inside of a class? Do you have any link to support that opinion?  I have read the link you provided many years ago. Unfortunately it has only 6 hits for `$this->__` None of it is direct call of PHP magic methods...

Comment: Yes, the only magic in them is that they can be called by you, but by other PHP features/functions too. In the source code they refer to them as "handlers": https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c#L55

Comment: Your link have 0 __invoke search hits ;) I'll play as if magic methods are callable like regular methods.